# Change is key-mapping is not remembered in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, keyboard, xmodmap

I have mapped my PageDown key to the Return command on my keyboard as the original Return key is broken. I used the following command [ I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 ]:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 117=Return'
```

It works all right. However, it does not work after I restart the system. How to make the system remember this setting forever ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

`keycode 117=Return`

to the file `.Xmodmap` in your user directory. (You might need to create it)